# Size :pseudo element relevant to its parent size?

Tags: css

Is it possible to size a `:pseudo` element relevant to its parent size?

I have a WordPress site where I use a `:pseudo` element (`.rectangle`) for some headings on the page. I'd like the icon to size itself relevant to its heading size. So let's say the `<h1>` has a font-size of `30px`, now the icon would also be `30px` a.s.o.

HTML

```
<h1 class="rectangle">lorem...</h1>
```

CSS

```
.rectangle:before {
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/the_real_url_to_the_image');
 background-position: center;
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 2rem;
 height: 2rem;
 margin-left: -3rem;
 margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

I do believe it would have to be done via jQuery or JavaScript but I'm new to them both so just wanted to ask what you guys think before I begin to pull my hair at some jQuery code.

Comment: I don't see a pseudo-selector? You have to add `::before` or `::after` to your `.rectangle` class for it to work, obviously.

Comment: My bad I have it in my code so it works, just forgot to paste it in here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider `em` unit and make the background to cover all the area:

```css
.rectangle::before {
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 background: url('https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=0') center/cover;
 width: 1em;
 height: 1em;
 margin-right:0.2em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="rectangle">lorem...</h1>

<h2 class="rectangle">lorem...</h2>
<p class="rectangle">lorem...</p>

<small class="rectangle">lorem...</small>
```